# How do I eliminate logging from a specific jar

Tags: slf4j, logback

I am using slf4j over logback in java.
How do I eliminate logging from a specific jar?
It prints a lot of info and I want to raise only its level to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify  in the `logback.xml` the package of classes that you do not want in the logs:

```xml
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" />
```

<sub>* The value of the `level` attribute admitting one of the case-insensitive string values TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ALL or OFF. The special case-insensitive value *INHERITED*, or its synonym *NULL*, will force the level of the logger to be inherited from higher up in the hierarchy.</sub>

See more in [Chapter 3: Logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) of the [The logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's not possible switch off logger from **specific jar**, but you can switch off logger for main **package of this jar**.

Like:

```
your.lib.main.package =  OFF
```